# Nested for-loop working incorrectly, with a logical error

Tags: java

I'm writing a small program for calculating sales statistics for a regional manager (as a school project), the user enters the number of sales divisions, the sales per quarter, per division.

The program outputs:

```
the sales (correctly)

the sales change from last quarter per division (correctly)

the quarterly totals (correctly)

the division totals (correctly)

the division averages (correctly)

the top division per quarter (incorrectly, logical error)
```

using the sales figures below, I should be receiving a result of 3,5,2,2 for the top  divisions per quarter. Using other data is giving the same logical error (different result, still wrong.)

The only place this is calculated is a small 12 line segment of code.
The rest of the code has been tested and is working correctly, my mistake must be here, in this snippet.

```
    int[] topDivQuarter = new int[4];

    for(int quarter=0; quarter < 4; quarter++){
        topDivQuarter[quarter] = 0; //Initialize at zero so division one is default top.
        for(int div=1; div < divNumb ; div++){ 
            //remember division first here, unlike the rest of the nested for loops.
            //Initialized to one because need to compare to previous division
            if ((sales[div][quarter]) > (sales[div - 1][quarter])){
                topDivQuarter[quarter] = div;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have consulted with two friends, none of us can find the error.

test sales i have been using,

divisions 5,

div 1 quarter 1: 1

div 1 quarter 2: 2

div 1 quarter 3: 3

div 1 quarter 4: 4

div 2 quarter 1: 5

... (12345678912345678912)

result has been 4,4,3,3, should be 3,5,2,2 as top division per quarter.

Please excuse the formatting of the output, I'm fixing that now that I'm stumped on this error.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in your IDE debugger? If not, that is the place to start. Examine the variables at each step to understand where it is deviating from your expectations.  BTW, using a 2D array to represent this type of data is very 1960's Fortran.  This is the 21st century and you should be using appropriate classes and data structures.

Comment: "using a 2D array to represent this type of data is very 1960's Fortran" good one! Try to provide a [mcve] *here*, not a link.

Comment: @JimGarrison The 2D array is just because it's a school project, it's not something I would usually use. I much prefer working with classes.

I'm crawling through the debugger atm, but I'm inexperienced with using it. Just means it'll take a little longer to figure things out (which I am using).

Comment: @Shadowfax I thought the snippet I provided would be all people needed, It should be some small error I'm probably overlooking. Or bad formatting causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
if ((sales[div][quarter]) > (sales[div - 1][quarter]))
```

you are only comparing sales numbers between two consecutive divisions. You should be comparing sales numbers between the top division so far and the current division:

```
if ((sales[div][quarter]) > (sales[topDivQuarter[quarter]][quarter]))
```

Comment: Nailed it, I knew it was something silly I was overlooking, yet I couldn't see it after staring at it for 40 minutes. Thank you so much for your time.